# Angular JS navigation and the # sign

Tags: angularjs

When creating, for example, dropdown menus I use the # sign on the link that toggles the dropdown. It works just fine with just for that and many other things where I need a link just to do something and stay on the same page.

Now I'm using angular and the problem I face is that when I use this sign on a link it thinks I'm referencing the route for `/` so that the app goes to the first screen.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: If the links don't actually link to anything, you should be using styled `span` tags that look clickable.

Comment: That's a fine solution that I didn't think before. Thanks very much @tymeJV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know another "ugly" workaround is to put **href="javascript:;"** to avoid the unintended navigation.

Or **remove the href** altogether but then when you mouseover you have no pointer. you need to add this to your CSS as described on UI Bootstrap page.

From: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

> Original Bootstrap's CSS depends on empty href attributes to style
>   cursors for several components (pagination, tabs etc.). But in
>   AngularJS adding empty href attributes to link tags will cause
>   unwanted route changes. This is why we need to remove empty href
>   attributes from directive templates and as a result styling is not
>   applied correctly. The remedy is simple, just add the following
>   styling to your application:

```
.nav, .pagination, .carousel, .panel-title a { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Angular-ui's solution is a bit problematic when it comes to accessibility. Anchors are not keyboard accessible by default unless they have href-attributes.